# how to update latest version of without uninstall older application manually

Tags: android, eclipse

I am android developer. This is my second android aplication which is the latest version of others. when i want to install this latest version i found some crash caused by i forget to uninstall my older version before. when i run by eclipse, eclipse uninstall them automatically before installed the latest version.it would be great if i can do it on my program.  because my application used by common people and maybe they had not any experience using android. as developer i should fix this issue. but i have no idea.

Comment: By default, Android will overwrite the data without uninstalling the app. But since you said that Eclipse uninstalled your old app, did you by any chance using different keystore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the previous installed app has a differente Signature.

Probably you installed the app with a different computer or Eclipse installation